# Dividend tax for Non Resident Alien owning US domiciled international stocks ETF

Tags: united-states, taxes, etf, non-resident, dividends

What is the US dividend tax rate for a non-resident alien owning a US domiciled ETF holding non-US companies?  Assume no tax treaty so the tax rate for the SPY ETF would be 30%.

An example would be a Hong Kong resident purchasing the MSCI China (MCHI) ETF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the US dividend tax rate for a non-resident alien owning a US domiciled ETF holding non-US companies? Assume no tax treaty so the tax rate for the SPY ETF would be 30%.

The tax would still be 30%.

This is precisely why US ETFs are generally unattractive to non-resident aliens, especially if they are resident in jurisdictions that have no applicable tax treaties with the US.

The Bogleheads wiki has an article about [nonresident alien taxation](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Nonresident_alien_taxation#Are_dividends_taxable_for_a_nonresident_alien.3F). Excerpt:

> Apart from an exemption for some US source 'portfolio interest' income ... US withholding tax applies regardless of the actual assets held by a US domiciled ETF. Even if all of the ETF's assets are non-US stocks, the US will still take 30% or lower treaty rate in dividend tax.